# Can i pass spring security credentials from grails to react?

Tags: spring, reactjs, grails, react-router, grails3

The site i am currently working on has been build in grails 3. The previous developers have build the majority of the front end in gsp, The end goal is to use react on the front end and just use grails as a rest api.

I am currently tasked with creating a new edition for the site and it will be the first component in react that needs authentication credentials to interact with users data.

this needs to be done before the rest of the site is transitioned here and there too react.

is there a way that i can gain access to a user's information that has signed in using gsp pages in react?

So i need to somehow securely pass the users information that is currently signed in on the non react site to the new react section without them having to sign in again. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is your grails backend issue a JWT token. This token identifies the user and can be used to securely access your API. Then you can have an API endpoint that returns detailed user information, if you need.

Comment: Great thank you i will look into them and let you know how i get on, thats a great help :)